# How to check if model in on CUDA?

Tags: pytorch

I would like to check if model is on CUDA. How to do that?

```py
import torch
import torchvision
model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
model.to('cuda')
```

Seams that `model.is_cuda()` is not working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code should do it:

```py
import torch
import torchvision
model = torchvision.models.resnet18()
model.to('cuda')
next(model.parameters()).is_cuda
```

Out:

```
True
```

Note there is no `is_cuda()` method inside `nn.Module`.
Also note `model.to('cuda')` is the same as `model.cuda()` and both are inplace.

On the other hand moving the `data.to('cuda')` is not inplace and you typically call:

```py
data = data.to('cuda')
```

to move the data to CUDA.